# Can't Delete file Macbook Pro (Stuck in Trash)

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro

I dunno when I deleted this file (its an avi), its been in the trash for awhile. Today I went to empty the trash and this one file can't claims to be in use. But I have restarted, shut down my mac several times, I've also used my media player several times since last using that file.

So I guess Im trying to find out how to find whats using the file or at least making it appear as such. So I can go about deleting it finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `lsof ~/.Trash/*.avi` from Terminal should show you what has the file open.  If necessary you could then use `kill` with the pid reported by `lsof` to force quit the program.

Comment: Might need a `sudo` there too.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -laeO@ ~/.Trash/*.avi` will show you information about other attributes that may be set on the file that may be keeping it from being deleted. There are different instructions for clearing different kinds of attributes depending on what's set, so if @geekosaur was wrong and nothing keeps re-opening that file after every reboot, update your Question with the output of that `ls` command and I can tell you want to do.

You may also be suffering from some sort of volume data or directory data corruption on your drive. Consider doing a "Repair Disk" and perhaps even a "Repair Disk Permissions" from Disk Utility.